# Как расположить кнопки рядом QT Designer

Tags: qt-designer

Начал изучать QT Designer. Попробовал построить пробный интерфейс с кнопками (менюшкой) слева и контентом справа. Кнопки должны быть фиксированного размера и располагаться друг под дружкой, как у меня, однако я использовал Frame и вертикальную политику Maximum, чтобы так сделать. Можно ли расположить кнопки также, но без Frame?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы считаете что форма будет лучше выглядеть без  `Frame`? Также вам надо опубликовать модуль `.ui`.

Comment: @S.Nick Я не считаю, что форма будет лучше выглядеть без Frame, в дизайне интерфейсов я не имею большого опыта, поэтому мне не хотелось захламлять форму дополнительными Frame. Опубликовать модуль .ui, означает просто прикрепить файл с этим расширением?

Comment: Pahan, вы правильно используете левый Frame для размещения кнопок. Да, опубликовать модуль .ui, означает просто прикрепить файл с этим расширением, но мне добавить больше нечего, все сказал в первом предложении.

Comment: @S.Nick, благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это оптимальное решение для расположения кнопок.

Можно спокойно использовать левый `Frame` для подобного расположения кнопок.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).